# Catching full output from subprocess script using subprocess.run in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to set up a `master.py` script that would call a set of individual Python scripts. For sake of simplicity, let's only consider one very basic such script: `counting.py` which just counts up with 1 second pauses:

```
# counting.py file
import time
for i in range(10000):
    print(f"Counting: {i}")
    time.sleep(1)
```

In the `master.py`, I use `subprocess.run()` to call `counting.py` which is located in the same folder. In the snippet below, `sys.executable` returns the path to the Python executable in the virtual environment. I also use the `multiprocessing` module to control timeouts: if `counting.py` runs longer than 60 seconds, process must be terminated. The code in `master.py` is as follows:

```
import subprocess
import multiprocessing
import sys
from pathlib import Path

def run_file(filename):

    cmd = [sys.executable, str(Path('.').cwd() / f'{filename}.py')]
    
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
        print("Subprocess output:\n", result)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error at {filename} when calling the command:\n\t{cmd}")
        print(f"Full traceback:\n{e}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_file, args=("counting",))
    p.start()
    # Wait for 60 seconds or until process finishes
    p.join(60)
    if p.is_alive():
        print("Timeout! Killing the process...")
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
```

The issue: Even though the code itself runs properly, I am unable to log any of the output while running `master.py`. Based on the documentation of the `subprocess` module, I had the impression that the `shell` and `stdout` arguments of `subprocess.run()` account for this exactly. I would like to see the same output as the one I get when only running `counting.py`, i.e.:

```
Counting 1
Counting 2
Counting 3
...
```

Comment: You could try to `read` from `result.stdout`. Or you could give a file handler (instead of PIPE) to stdout argument. The result will go to that file.

Comment: thanks for the tip @AxeonThra, however, I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to do that. I tried ```with subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc: print(proc.stdout.read())``` but this didn't print anything. Also tried ```for line in result.stdout.read(): print(line)```, again no output.

Comment: Are you sure the program is giving output via stdout and not via stderr?

Comment: I see that you used a list with shell=True. This is not probably what is needed. On POSIX with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell. This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell (from docs)

Comment: @AxeonThra, I changed `cmd` from list to string format. It looks like this: ```C:\Users\lazarea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe "G:\project\counting.py"```. I verified that this works when copy-pasted into the command line: counting starts as expected. However, it seems `subprocess.run()` never returns anything, the `print("Subprocess output:\n", result)` line never gets executed because of the timeout. But then how can I catch the output of that subprocess in `master.py`?

Comment: Tried all the following cases based on the documentation but I'm still unable to catch the output of the subprocess:
`result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True)`; 
`result = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True)` ;
`result =subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True)` ;
in each cases, `cmd` is a string as shown in my previous comment: `C:\Users\lazarea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe "G:\project\counting.py"`. When pasting it to shell, this single command runs as expected!

Comment: Interestingly, when executing a simple `subprocess.run(cmd)` in the console of PyCharm, *without* any of the additional arguments such as `capture_output`, it works perfectly. It only refuses to print the expected output from the subprocess when executing in the command line.

Comment: @lazarea thank you. I was going in circles trying to figure out how to get my command to output and everyone saying to use the pipes.... changing it to simply `subprocess.run(cmd)` worked. Its odd cause in another section of my code I use the pipes and it work there. Its basically the exact same code just running the same command with differing command args. Also I thought that first use might be messing with the second use of `.run` but it happened even when the code never used the first instance of `.run`. Weird but its working.